# JS amending table content after a second click on the button

Tags: javascript, html

I need a function to change any random table cell content to some other.
HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen, projection">
    <title>Lab1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>1 Laboratorinis darbas </h1>
<table id="myTable">
  <caption id=a><strong>Automobiliai</caption></strong>
  <tr>
    <th>Modelis</th>
    <th>Gamintojas</th>
    <th>Metai</th>
    <th>Variklio Numeris</th>
  </tr>
<script>
arraytotable()
secondClick()
</script>
</table>
<button type="button" id="test" onclick="pavadinimas(); secondClick()">Mygtukas</button>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Add another line" onclick="addField(this);" />
</body>
</html>
```

JS code to put an array into my table:

```
function arraytotable(){
var array = [
["A4", "Audi", "2015", "1234"],
["A3", "Audi", "2011", "1542"],
["335i", "BMW", "2012", "9874"],
["440d", "BMW", "2015", "1975"],
["Civic", "Honda", "2002", "6574"]]

var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
// create a new row
var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
{
// create a new cell
var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);

// add value to the cell
cell.innerHTML = array[i][j];
}
}
```

I started by including the code that would count the number of clicks done on that button, but I don't know how to access my table data in that function:

```
var cnt=-1;

    function secondClick(){
     cnt+=1;
     console.log(cnt);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this code fragment to call the table from another function and change the value in it:

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
table.rows[].cells[].innerHTML = array[][].bold();
```

Comment: Could you make this as the accepted answer if it fixed your problem and put the full code block in that fixed the problem in case other people run into the same problem?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If we let the button call a function, we can use that function to count the number of clicks, and call `arraytotable` if needed

---

> but I don't know how to access my table data in that function

No need, you've already used `document.getElementById("myTable")` to get the table inside the `arraytotable` function.

```js
var cnt=0;
function onButtonClick(){
    cnt+=1;
    if (cnt === 2) {
        arraytotable();
    }
}

function arraytotable(){
    var array = [
        ["A4", "Audi", "2015", "1234"],
        ["A3", "Audi", "2011", "1542"],
        ["335i", "BMW", "2012", "9874"],
        ["440d", "BMW", "2015", "1975"],
        ["Civic", "Honda", "2002", "6574"]
    ];

    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        // create a new row
        var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);

        for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            
            // create a new cell
            var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);

            // add value to the cell
            cell.innerHTML = array[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>1 Laboratorinis darbas </h1>
<table id="myTable">
    <caption id=a><strong>Automobiliai</caption></strong>
    <tr>
        <th>Modelis</th>
        <th>Gamintojas</th>
        <th>Metai</th>
        <th>Variklio Numeris</th>
    </tr>
</table>    

<button type="button" id="test" onclick="onButtonClick()">Mygtukas</button>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Add another line" onclick="addField(this);" />
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't need to call the arraytotable function again. The outcome I need is that when a button is clicked for the second time, one random value from the table has to change to any random value.
For example, i click the button second time and then the year value from 1st row changes to 2020 from 2015